# Rasa NLU - Understanding Training Data

Tags: machine-learning, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am having a hard time understanding training data in rasa nlu. Say I want to have training data where someone is informing someone of animals they can buy. For clarity I'll use markdown format:

Say the user is hypothetically responding to a question:

***"What kind of animal would you like to buy?"***

There are only so many different ways of saying you want to buy something.
So take the below example:

```
##intent:inform
- [cat](animal)
- buy [cat](animal)
- I would like to buy a [cat](animal)
```

Would I need to repeat this for every type of animal I intended to handle? Like below?

```
##intent:inform
- [cat](animal)
- [dog](animal)
- [parrot](animal)
- buy [cat](animal)
- buy [dog](animal)
- buy [parrot](animal)
- I would like to buy a [cat](animal)
- I would like to buy a [dog](animal)
- I would like to buy a [parrot](animal)
```

Also, I noticed that in rasa's restaurant bot, they sometimes repeat the same example over and over again, sometimes up to seven times, like below:

```
##intent:inform
- [cat](animal)
- [cat](animal)
- [cat](animal)
- [cat](animal)
- [cat](animal)
- buy [cat](animal)
- I would like to buy a [cat](animal)
```

Why is that necessary? What affect does this have on the understanding? How would more occurrences of the same single word in the same position be an indicator that it is an appropriate response, especially if you had something like the below where a different value of the same entity was repeated the same amount of times?

```
##intent:inform
- [cat](animal)
- [cat](animal)
- [cat](animal)
- [cat](animal)
- [cat](animal)
- buy [cat](animal)
- I would like to buy a [cat](animal)
- [dog](animal)
- [dog](animal)
- [dog](animal)
- [dog](animal)
- [dog](animal)
- buy [dog](animal)
- I would like to buy a [dog](animal)
```

Thank you, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are only so many different ways of saying you want to buy something.

You may be surprised:

- Can I buy a dog?
- I want to buy a dog.
- I really want a dog.
- I'd love it if I owned a dog.
- I'm looking for a pet, maybe a dog.
- purchase dog
- adopt dog
- get a dog
- take a dog home with me

and I am sure the list continues for many more examples. That being said Rasa NLU should be able to learn and adapt off of a handful of examples. With some exceptions`adopt` may not have a strong relationship to `buy` for example and could be important to have as an example.

> Would I need to repeat this for every type of animal I intended to handle? Like below?

No that is not necessary. Each animal value is an entity and Rasa by default uses a CRF for entity recognition, which is what you are talking about here. The CRF is more about the structure of the sentence than it is the value of the word. You can see the features the CRF looks at in the [docs](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/pipeline/#ner-crf) and [code](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/extractors/crf_entity_extractor.py#L67):

```
  # Available features are:
  # ``low``, ``title``, ``suffix5``, ``suffix3``, ``suffix2``,
  # ``suffix1``, ``pos``, ``pos2``, ``prefix5``, ``prefix2``,
  # ``bias``, ``upper`` and ``digit``
  features: [["low", "title"], ["bias", "suffix3"], ["upper", "pos", "pos2"]]
```

That being said using different values for the entity can be a good way to get extra training data. You can use a tool like [chatito](https://github.com/rodrigopivi/Chatito) to generate the training data from patterns. But be careful about repeating patterns as you can [overfit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) the model to where it cannot generalize beyond the patterns you train for.

> they sometimes repeat the same example over and over again

You saw this in a Rasa data set? Here is the default [restaurant bot training data](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/data/examples/rasa/demo-rasa.md) and I don't see any repeats.

Repeating a single sentence over and over will re-inforce to the model that formats/words are important, this is a form of [oversampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling). This can be a good thing if you have very little training data or highly unbalanced training data. It can be a bad thing if you want to handle a lot of different ways to buy a pet as it can [overfit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) the model as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

> Would I need to repeat this for every type of animal I intended to
>   handle? Like below?

No, You do not need to specify every type of animal. But try to add few type of animal for each intent. For example your training sample contains such a things:

```
 - [cat](animal)
 - [dog](animal)
 - [parrot](animal)
 - buy [cat](animal)
 - I would like to buy a [parrot](animal)
```

When you have some context e.g: `I would like to buy a [animal]` it's not necessary to define every type of animal. The similarity algorithm find item based on other keywords. But when the context is less (single words) It is necessary to define different type of user Input.

Rasa use [StarSpace classifier](https://github.com/hadifar/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/classifiers/embedding_intent_classifier.py). It is recommended to use **~10-25 user samples** for **each intent** to get a reasonable response from ChatBot.

You can also modify [Rasa classifier](https://github.com/hadifar/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/classifiers/embedding_intent_classifier.py) to add word-vector features (Word2vec or Glove). In this case, Some generality will be added to model. And similar concepts, such as dog-cat will be detected more easily.

Comment: Hm, thanks for this, it is exactly the answer I was looking for. Do you know why in rasas example they specify the same single word multiple times in the training data though? For instance they may have just  “[cat](animal)” defined several times.

Comment: @CoffeeIsProgramming, Would please give me the link of such examples. In official example, in their github, the single word only appeared once. https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/data/examples/rasa/demo-rasa.md

Comment: Sure, it exists several times in their frankendata.json (old format). For instance do quick search on  "text": "cheap"

https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/blob/master/examples/restaurantbot/data/franken_data.json

I'm wondering if it is somehow to add "weight" to these words as opposed to other words in the english language, but it could just be poorly written training data. I'm really not sure.

Comment: @CoffeeIsProgramming, As far as I am aware there is no way to add weight to the examples. In a classifier repeating some examples just allow to classifier to learn more about them (sometimes overfit on that training example).